# Sublime sidebar menu right click items are greyed out. How do I resolve this?

Tags: sublimetext3

When I right click on items in my side bar, in order to modify files, all the options are greyed out like so:

[image]

It only happens in Sublime. I have tried Atom and it doesn't have this issue.

The application permissions have not changed and is owned by root:admin.

I have tried reinstalling Sublime to no avail.

I am using Sublime Text 3, on Mac Sierra.

Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found was to completely reinstall sublime